# pandas groupby with nested struct

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a large array of JSON data that I've loaded into Pandas but an important part of the data is a nested struct that has a dynamic group of keys and values. What I'm trying to do is try to be able to include that data after doing grouping or being able to perform general statistics based on that nested struct.

The data looks some like:

```
[
    {
        "error_count": 1,
        "id": "abcdef",
        "common_id": "A",
        "date": "2022-01-01",
        "errors": {
            "error1": "5",
        }
    },
    {
        "error_count": 2,
        "id": "ghijkl",
        "common_id": "A",
        "date": "2022-01-02",
        "errors": {
            "error7": "2",
            "error32": "2"
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

I'm trying to generate a table that can group by `common_id`, then `id`, then display the individual errors and the error value but the nested struct keys are dynamic and can be different for every record.

I'm also trying to generate a table of those dynamic errors and how many records have each error, possibly with the use of `groupby()` to group by date.

The data was originally in Spark but I found pyspark a but confusing so I'm trying to load the data into pandas instead because I thought it would be easier.

I've been trying to read as much as I can about pandas over the past several days but I'm afraid I'm pretty lost at this point. Maybe I'm not asking the right questions but I hope the people smarter than myself can help point me in the right direction.

**Desired outputs:**

For the first table:

```
common_id    id      error    error_val
A            abcdef  error1   5
             ghijkl  error7   2
                     error32  2
```

and something like this for the second table:

```
common_id    id      error    error_count
A            abcdef  error1   1
             ghijkl  error7   1
                     error32  1
```

or:

```
error    error_val    record_count
error1   5            1
error7   2            1
error32  2            1
```

or:

```
error    record_count
error1   1
error7   1
error32  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first output, you could use `json_normalize` to flatten your list of dictionaries (which I named `data` below) into a table; then `melt` it. The rest are cosmetic changes to get the output in the desired form:

```
first = pd.melt(pd.json_normalize(data).drop(columns=['error_count', 'date']), 
              id_vars=['common_id', 'id'], 
              var_name='error', value_name='error_val').dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
first['error'] = first['error'].str.split('.').str[1]
```

Output:

```
  common_id      id    error error_val
0         A  abcdef   error1         5
1         A  ghijkl   error7         2
2         A  ghijkl  error32         2
```

For the second output, you could use the DataFrame created in the step above (which I named `first`) and use `groupby` + `count`:

```
second = first.groupby(['common_id', 'id', 'error'])['error_val'].count().reset_index(name='error_count')
```

Output:

```
  common_id      id    error  error_count
0         A  abcdef   error1            1
1         A  ghijkl  error32            1
2         A  ghijkl   error7            1
```